# Display input from text area as HTML and assign IDs to the HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm using a function to add strings to an array from a textArea in a modal, then printing them to the DOM with innerHTML ([which I learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123786/populate-an-array-from-textarea-in-javascript)). The function is called with a button on the modal.

```
function setArray( ){
      let textAreaElement = document.getElementById('textToArray');
      let listArray = textAreaElement.value.trim().split('\n');
      console.log(listArray);
      document.getElementById('PrintToSidebar').innerHTML = listArray.join("<p>");//I want to add IDs in the <p> tags created here
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

That seems to be working well, but I also want to set an ID for each individual `<p>`, with the IDs being equal to the string values.

For example, if listArray = ["Line 1", "Line 2"], then my desired innerHTML would result in:

```
<p id="line-1">Line 1</p>
<p id="line-2">Line 2</p>
```

My searches seem to indicate I need to use the setAttribute method. But I'm also thinking I need to loop through listArray first.

I'm only a few days into Javascript (totally new to coding actually) so a detailed solution would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally don't use innerHTML and instead create the `p` tags with `document.createElement` so you can set their `id` attributes.

Comment: It's worth noting that the suggested `id`'s of `line 1` and `line 2` are [technically invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7873035/11700321) as an `id` cannot have a space in it. This can be easily mitigated though with the [Javascript Replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function to remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the array and create the `p` element dynamically with the help of `document.createElement("p)` which is the built in function, then set the text on `textContent` property and the id on `id` property of the newly created element.

I used `trim()` to remove the spaces from start and at the end of the string and `replace` to replace the spaces with `-`. `replace` first argument is a Regular Expressions which you can learn more on this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Last step is to append the newly created element to the dom.
t

```js
/* Appends the element to DOM*/
function display(ele) {
    const display = document.getElementById('PrintToSidebar');
    display.append(ele);
}

function setArray() {
    let textAreaElement = document.getElementById('textToArray');
    let listArray = textAreaElement.value.trim().split('\n');
    listArray.forEach(item => {
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = item;
        p.id = item.trim().replace(/\s/g, "-");
        display(p);
    });
}
```

```html
 <textarea id="textToArray">Line 1 
Line 1
</textarea>
<div id="PrintToSidebar"> </div>
<button onclick="setArray()">Generate tag</button>
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting this to work. I'm getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null," but I'll keep playing around with it. Thank you!

Comment: Because the 'display' div is not defined in your code. I have changed the code to append the element to `PrintToSidebar` element.  Please try now and let me know if you are still facing issue. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!